# Some Images not getting imported via Magmi into Magento. Broken image symbol in the admin panel

Tags: magento, magmi

While uploading products via Magmi on Magneto,a few of the products are not displaying images on the frontend. In the admin panel, I see a broken image symbol. The images are successfully placed in the /meda/import directory. I am sure this is not about permissions as this is happening only for a few products and the other products are getting imported properly with the images(all images are in a single directory). Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are the images very large? There are maximum file sizes that sometimes cause problems.

Comment: No, the images are all below 100kb and moreover a lot of other images with bigger sizes in the same directory are getting imported without any hassle.

Comment: Have a look at the url for the image that the browser's trying to load. You might spot a pattern in those that are broken.

Comment: I place all the images in /media/import and run magmi. I see that all the  images on the site are loaded from /media/catalog/product/*subdirectory*/*subdirectory* where the subdirectories are random numbers

In case where the product image is not getting loaded, the images are present but 0 Kb images. So wonder what could be the possible issue.

Comment: Does magmi have access to the images or their folders?

Comment: @PedroKTFC Thanks for the interest. Actually, the broken images had been cached the first time Magmi ran and it was repeatedly taking broken images from the cache folder instead of /media/import folder.

Comment: @tanzeemahmed : Is your issue solved?

Comment: @Rathinam Very late reply but yes it got solved :)

Comment: @tanzeemahmed Thanks for your response :)